# How to check if CapForm is set by default in the plot?

Tags: plotting, graphics, style, default

In this plot it seems like the `CapForm["Square"]` is set by default.

```
plot = Plot[1 + x^2, {x, -5, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.05], PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {0, 30}}]
```

[image]

Is there any way to check the default `CapForm["Square"]` exists there? 
 I tried `FullForm` but didn't see `CapForm` anywhere in the code.

```
plot // FullForm
```

EDIT:
As Alan mentioned in the comment it's from the docs. However, would it be possible to check from the `plot` instead? I want to use the method to check other parameters that I don't know as well. They may exist in docs but I think this method is better in some cases. Like I didn't know `CapForm` exists and it would be good if I can use the method to check all default parameters.

Comment: From the [docs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CapForm.html): 'In 2D, the default is CapForm["Square"]. In 3D, the default is CapForm["Round"].'

Comment: @Alan would it be possible to check from the plot instead? I want to use the method to check other parameters that I don't know as well. They may exist in docs but I think this method is better in some cases. Like I didn't know CapForm exists and it would be good if I can use the method to check all default parameters.

Comment: "I want to use the method to check other parameters that I don't know as well" - can you list those parameters? As it is written this question is about `CapForm` and has been answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if the following is a satisfying answer.

You can run

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics"}]
```

and at some point you will see among other things.

> `CapForm -> "Square"`

Edit: this is a much needed clarification after the comments.

For the `Plot3D` you can use

```
CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Graphics3D"}]
```

and again it spits out many things among them is

> `CapForm -> "Round"`

More extra stuff, since the OP mentions that they want to check other information as well

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
PrintDefinitions[Plot]
```

and likewise for `Plot3D`. This will open up a pop-up window.

Moving on

```
Options[Plot]
```

gives much info, though nothing about `CapForm`. Likewise you can use `Options[Plot3D]`.

Finally, there's also

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", Plot]
```

and of course

```
Charting`ResolvePlotTheme["Default", Plot3D]
```

that don't contain `CapForm` but other useful information.

Comment: That is nice. Would `Plot`, `Plot3D` be `Graphics`? Would it be possible to check for a funciton such as `Plot`? I tried `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Plot"}]` but it returns an empty list.

Comment: @hana For disambiguation, please see [this link](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html). Please, scroll down to `Basic Examples` where you can find `Use plot functions to automatically create Graphics from different types of data`. Also, [this one](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html). Does this answer your query?

Comment: Not really. I assumed you meant to say that `Plot` is one type of `Graphics` but from Alan's comment it seems like `Plot3D` is not considered `Graphics`. Would it be possible to check all default paratemeters of a function such as `Plot`, `Plot3D`?

Comment: @hana ok I think I understood what went on. Please see my updated answer. I think I answered. You can use `Grpahics` and `Graphics3D` to get the different answers for `CapForm`. Since you mentioned that you wanted to check extra stuff, I also included some other commands that can be hopefully useful!

Answer (score 2):

```
plot = Plot[1 + x^2, {x, -5, 5}, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  PlotStyle -> {Red, CapForm["Round"], Thickness[0.05]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-6, 6}, {0, 30}}]
```

Now execute:

```
plot[[1]] // Short[#, 5] &

Cases[plot[[1]], CapForm[_], Infinity]
```

> {CapForm["Round"]}

If you don't specify an explicit setting, default setting are used but not listed (that you can get as in the other answer).

Comment: (+1) very nice and useful to check at the level of the specific plot directly! I am a bit confused by the scope because, under my reply it was explicitly written *Would it be possible to check all default paratemeters of a function such as Plot, Plot3D*. Anyway, cool stuff!!!